# Membership for Group of people. One payer

Tags: civimember, civigroup

I have a case where I need the ability for a user to fill out and submit a membership application for himself and other people.

Specific Requirements:

- Single transaction: The user pays for himself and everyone else, but everyone gets a membership
- The cost is not fixed: $75 dollars per person  (ex: Group of 5 = $375, group of 2 = $150)
- Renewal reminders only sent to the originator.
- Everyone gets assigned to a group with a name assigned by the user

Is this possible to do with CiviCRM? I can't seem to find an online example or documentation on this specific use case.

Edit: I'm using Joomla! 3.9.16

Comment: Have you read up about Inherited Memberships? Would that work for you or will the renewal of each of these Memberships be done by each separate Group Member.

Comment: What CMS are you using. If Drupal 7 then webform_civicrm is good for bending around such weird situations. If WP then Caldera Forms. If D8 then possibly webform_civicrm but it is not as mature as the D7 version yet

Comment: @petednz - fuzion Looks like I would be looking to use the inherited membership feature because I need renewals handled by one person for the group

Comment: i will add as answer. pls 'accept' it

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal CMS than you can do this by using webform and webform civicrm module and probably CiviRules. You will need to create 2 membership type Member and Additional member. Setup webform to accept # of contacts with 1st contact as set to use Member membership type and rest of the contact set to Additional member membership.

Set up reminder for membership type member to send membership for primary member.

(Not sure if the same process can be done in wordpress caldera form plugin)

Comment: I just added my CMS to the OP. Unfortunately I am using Joomla and I cannot change platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you read up about Inherited Memberships if you want to treat this as a single 'entity' which just the primary member manages in terms of the renewal

Comment: I see that I can give an organization a membership and it applies to all members of that organization, but there are still many problems. First, the price needs to vary based on the amount of members with the relationship to the organization. Second, these people may or may not be in the system and may or may not have the necessary relationship to the organization. That means, the user on the frontend would need an option to create or update a bunch of users, assign them a relationship to the org and then register the organization as a member with a calculated sum based on relationship total

Comment: "the price needs to vary based on the amount of members with the relationship to the organization" - a price set can offer a numeric field so they can say eg '50 employees' and be charged 50 x the fee

Comment: "Second, these people may or may not be in the system and may or may not have the necessary relationship to the organization " In Drupal (and I expect WP) you can use Webform (Caldera forms) to set up forms so folk can create the necessary related contacts. obviously is this is a large number it may get quite involved but we have built similar forms for users.

Comment: ah sorry - just read about joomla. fyi you can in theory have more than one system wired in to civicrm but the idea of having D or WP wired in just to give you these forms may seem excessive.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I've gotten the form to allow a person to create a membership on behalf of an organization for $75 * Amount of members. Unless I am missing something, it looks like I'll have to build something out that will allow me to capture the "Additional Members"

Comment: so i am thinking an extension could add a feature to a Profile so that if I am sent a checksum (assuming your members do not have joomla logins - maybe they do), and i fill in a profile with name John Doe, and the extension creates the relationship of whatever RelType is hard coded in extension.